# ngAnimate dependency causing app not to display

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, ng-animate

I'm trying to introduce animations into my application however when I include the ngAnimate dependency in my application, it doesn't load nor do I get any errors in the console which is making it pretty hard to debug.

index.html:

```
<html>
<head >
    <!-- Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Style%20Library/projects/spDash/app/css/main.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Style%20Library/projects/spDash/app/css/sidebar.css"/>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Style%20Library/projects/spDash/app/css/bootstrap3.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="mdContainer" ng-cloak>
        <!-- Navigation --> 
        <div id='mdSidebar'>
            <ul>
               <li id="menuHome"><a href='#/home'><span>Home</span></a></li>
               <li id="menuUsers"><a href='#/userView'><span>Users</span></a></li>
               <li id="menuGroups"><a href='#/groupView'><span>Groups</span></a></li>
               <li id="menuSites"><a href='#/sitesView'><span>Sites</span></a></li>
               <li id="menuReports"><a href='#'><span>Reports</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <!-- Main view --> 
        <ng-view>
            <div class="mainView">
                <h1 class="topPanel">This is place holder text until I build a home page</h1>
            </div>
        </ng-view>
    </div>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://hosted.compulite.ca/Style%20Library/projects/spDash/app/js/spAppLoader.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

scriptAppLoader.js:

```
$LAB
    .script("//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular-animate.js")
    .script("//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular-route.js")
    /*.script("//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular-route.min.js")*/
    /*.script("//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular-animate.min.js")*/   
    /*.script("//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.4.5/select2.min.js")*/
    .script("//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.4.5/select2.js")
    .script("https://hosted.compulite.ca/Style%20Library/projects/spDash/app/js/app.js")
    .script("//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.10.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js")
    .script("https://hosted.compulite.ca/Style%20Library/projects/spDash/app/js/controllers/userCtrl.js")
    .script("https://hosted.compulite.ca/Style%20Library/projects/spDash/app/js/controllers/groupCtrl.js")
    .script("https://hosted.compulite.ca/Style%20Library/projects/spDash/app/js/controllers/newGroupCtrl.js")
    .script("https://hosted.compulite.ca/Style%20Library/projects/spDash/app/js/controllers/siteCtrl.js")
    .script("https://hosted.compulite.ca/Style%20Library/projects/spDash/app/js/services/userServices.js")
    .script("https://hosted.compulite.ca/Style%20Library/projects/spDash/app/js/services/groupServices.js")
    .script("https://hosted.compulite.ca/Style%20Library/projects/spDash/app/js/services/siteServices.js")
    .wait(function(){
          var root = document.getElementById('mdContainer')
          angular.bootstrap(root ,['spApp']);
        })
```

app.js:

```
var spApp = angular.module('spApp', ['ngRoute','ngAnimate','ui.bootstrap'])
    .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
        var rootUrl = '/Style%20Library/projects/spDash/app/partials/';

        $routeProvider
        .when('/home', 
        {
            templateUrl: rootUrl+'home.html'
        })
        .when('/userView', 
        {
            templateUrl: rootUrl+'userView.html', 
            controller: 'userCtrl'
        })
        .when('/groupView', 
        {
            templateUrl: rootUrl+'groupsView.html', 
            controller: 'groupCtrl' 
        })
        .when('/sitesView',
        {
            templateUrl: rootUrl+'sitesview.html',
            controller: 'sitesCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo:'/home'});
        //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
```

Comment: Have you checked the contents of the animate.js file in your sources to see if it has content?

Comment: What error are you getting in console?  Also, where are you including angular itself?  Your scriptAppLoader starts off with animate, and angular is not loaded on the page.

Comment: Yup, I'm getting them from the google CDN and also tried the code.angular cdn

Comment: @TheSharpieOne I'm running this application on SharePoint so I've got jquery and angular in the sharepoint template. These run first always and my application has no problem loading doing it like this. I'm not getting errors in the console. When I remove ngCloak the app container shows up but the views do not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ngRoute no longer working after injecting ngAnimate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21562363/ngroute-no-longer-working-after-injecting-nganimate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

angular.js was version 1.2.4

angular-animate.js was version 1.2.10

Update so they're the latest versions and you're good.

Comment: Ayone having issues with 1.3.15 in the same way ? It is simply not recognising the checked and loaded angular-animate.js file...
Inject like this ...
---
angular.module('baApp')
    .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope','$location','localStorageService','ngAnimate'...