# ngRoute no longer working after injecting ngAnimate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-animate

I wanted to animate my application so I injected ngAnimate but now none of my views are displaying:

```
var spApp = angular.module('spApp', ['ngRoute','ui.bootstrap', 'ngAnimate'])
    .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
        var rootUrl = '/Style%20Library/projects/spDash/app/partials/';
        $routeProvider
        .when('/home', 
        {
            templateUrl: rootUrl+'home.html'
        })
        .when('/userView', 
        {
            templateUrl: rootUrl+'userView.html', 
            controller: 'userCtrl'
        })
        .when('/groupView', 
        {
            templateUrl: rootUrl+'groupsView.html', 
            controller: 'groupCtrl' 
        })
        .when('/sitesView',
        {
            templateUrl: rootUrl+'sitesview.html',
            controller: 'sitesCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo:'/home'});
        //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
```

Is this incorrect?

Comment: ngAnimate is on a separate source file, is it included in your app?

Comment: Yea ive included the file using LABjs and then bootstraped the application manually. I haven't declared any CSS rules, could that be the reason?

Comment: This is a plunker which some of the code: http://plnkr.co/edit/P8s2G5ujBMYt1HTs7iNA?p=preview

Comment: Nope. ngAnimate only affects css rendering and even with wrong css it still moves you between pages

Comment: Before, I had ng-cloak in my index.html file and nothing at all would show up. I had to remove it to get the index to show but none of the routes work now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version between angular and animate weren't the same. Angular was 1.2.4 while animate was 1.2.10.

Upgrading angular solved the issue.

Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

Your application demo in the plunker is missing the app declaration like this for example:

```
<body ng-app="spApp">
```

There is controller or main controller defined.

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
      <ng-view></ng-view>
</div>
```

More over I am not sure about your script declaration.

Here is a plunker configured:

http://plnkr.co/edit/tjDnzBu2PVSADKtbEFrL?p=preview

Here's a plunker with a few HTML files. In the original, you had "home.js" instead of "home.html", but when the partials are saved as HTML they seem to work fine.

http://plnkr.co/edit/aa6fKoBljxRHe4zVPYBl?p=preview

Comment: you removed the animate.js? Don't I need that

Comment: When you say it worked, what do you mean and I'm not sure what latar is. So you completely removed that line?

Comment: I tried doing this but it didn't solve the issue for me. When you said it worked, were you able to see the other views (ie. Users, groups)? I'm just getting the nav bar.

Comment: I'm manually bootstrapping ng-app into the application using labjs. Let me try this and see if that works in the plunker

Comment: @Batman I added a plunker demo with the addtional details. hope it helps

Comment: Yea I'm looking at it right now but even with your changes my partial views still don't work

Comment: partials were not on the plunker that might be it

Comment: They're in the LABjs. I've been loading all my controllers, services and modules that way without issue. But when I introduce ngAnimate, everything kinda breaks.

Comment: Hmm yea, the last edit does show it working. Should I not be using LABjs then? It's been working perfectly for me so far and makes adding to the application really easy. Plus I really need to bootstrap the app manually, it doesn't work in my environment if I don't.